# ¿Como cargar ciertas tablas de un DataGrid - MVVM - UWP?

Tags: c#, datagrid, sql

Es que quiero crear un Datagrid para cargar una consulta de la base de datos, usando este ejemplo https://github.com/RSuter/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid pero no entiendo exactamente como cargo la lista.

Pero encontre este codigo

```
<controls: DataGrid x:Name = "DataGrid" ItemsSource = "{Binding Plactas}" SelectedItem = "{Binding PlactaSelected, Mode = TwoWay}" DefaultOrderIndex = "0" SelectionMode = "Extended">
```

En el ViewModel ya tengo la lista llamada `Plactas` y pues muestra la informacion, pero nesecito que aparezcan solo ciertas columnas.

Lo otro es que no se que otra opcion tenga para crear DataGrids

Comment: El codigo que te falla debe ir en la pregunta.

Comment: lo que pasa es que era una duda que tenia hace como 1 mes, y pues ya la solucione, pero me la borraron, tengo que esperar un rato o mañana para contestar la pregunta, es muy dificil de hallar documentacion de lo que me paso, asi que lo resolvi con mis propios medios.

Comment: La pregunta esa mal formada, asi que por favor, esta muy bien que pongas la pregunta y la contestes inmediatamente. Pero como esta en este momento, no se entiende la pregunta, es demasiado amplia. redacta mejor la pregunta, tene en cuenta que no es un Datagrid comun por ejemplo, si no uno de una libreria en particular. Si no, por mas que pongas todo, nadie va a encontrar tu pregunta y la respuesta. Explica cual es el problema, pone un titulo mejor, y despues agrega la respuesta. Si no, va a pasar lo mismo de antes.

Comment: vale, mirare que pregunta hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MUY MUY IMPORTANTE, NO CREAR COLUMNAS VACÍAS, SIN VINCULACIÓN, SI USTED CRANCA GENERARÁ UN ERROR Y LA LISTA NO SE CARGARÁ, SI CREE 3 COLUMNAS, DEBE ENLACE A LA LISTA EN LAS TRES COLUMNAS

Lo primero es lo primero: veremos qué documentación tenemos sobre esto, hay dos bibliotecas OpenSource que nos permiten generar DataGrids en UWP, entiendo que el DataGrid no puede ser nativo dentro del entorno de desarrollo de UWP, por lo que al revisar vemos que tiene 2 formas este primer enlace:

1- Página de la documentación: https://github.com/RSuter/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid

Esto es muy fácil de cargar fácilmente:

Descargue el NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MyToolkit.Extended/

o busque en la ventana de NuGet: "MyToolkit.Extended" e instale

importar el uso en XAML: `xmlns:controls="using:MyToolkit.Controls"` El nombre Plactas es la lista en el VIEWMODEL y se declara así

```
public List<Placta> Plactas { get => plactas; set => Set(ref plactas, value); }
private List<Placta> plactas;
```

Este es el Código en XAML de la Lista:

```
<Grid>
  <controls: DataGrid x: Name = "DataGrid" ItemsSource = "{Binding Plactas}" SelectedItem = "{Binding PlactaSelected, Mode = TwoWay}" DefaultOrderIndex = "0" SelectionMode = "Extended">
     <controls: DataGrid.Columns> <!--This is important here are Columns. Code and Name are fields in the Model-->
         <controls: DataGridTextColumn Width = "150" Header = "Code" Binding = "{Binding Code}" />
         <controls: DataGridTextColumn Width = "300" Header = "Name" Binding = "{Binding Name}" />
      </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
      <controls: DataGrid.ItemDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate> <!--Here create comments when you selected item-->
                 <StackPanel Margin = "10,10,10,5">
                       <TextBlock Text = "Date of creation:" FontWeight = "Bold" />
                       <TextBlock Text = "{Binding FCreated}" />
                  </StackPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
       </controls:DataGrid.ItemDetailsTemplate>
   </controls: DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

¡¡¡FÁCIL!!! pero este diseño puede no llamar la atención, no te preocupes, por eso estoy aquí, hay otra biblioteca OpenSource ... así que veremos una segunda opción

2- Página de la documentación: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid

Descargue el NuGet: https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit

o busque en la ventana de NuGet: "Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid" e instale

importar el uso en XAML: `xmlns:control="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"`

Crear código en XAML:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="4">
     <control:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Plactas}" Margin="12" GridLinesVisibility="All" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
           <control:DataGrid.Columns>
                  <control:DataGridTextColumn Header="Mountain" Tag="Mountain" Binding="{Binding Codigo}"/>
```

ya con esto se cargaría la lista en el DataGrid

Lo bueno de este tipo de DataGrid es que permite la edición mucho mejor, aquí les dejo la documentación para que pueda visualizar los campos y las líneas: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/communitytoolkit/controls / datagrid_guidance / styling_formatting_options

Este es el resultado:

Encima del primer diseño de DataGrid:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el segundo diseño:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]